# How to read Interbase database with Cyrillic text content

Tags: python, interbase

I am using pyfirebirdsql version 0.8.5 to connect to Interbase database.

```py
import firebirdsql

conn = firebirdsql.connect(
    host='192.168.133.121',
    database='E:\\test\test.gdb',
    port=3050,
    user='sysdba',
    password='masterkey'
    #charset="WIN1251"
    #charset="UTF8"

)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select column1 from table1")
for c in cur.fetchall():
    print(c)
conn.close()
```

When I try to run the script I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 15, in <module>
    for c in cur.fetchall():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebirdsql/fbcore.py", line 291, in fetchall
    return [tuple(r) for r in self._fetch_records]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebirdsql/fbcore.py", line 225, in _fetch_generator
    stmt_handle, self._xsqlda)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebirdsql/wireprotocol.py", line 728, in _op_fetch_response
    return self._parse_op_response()    # error occured
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firebirdsql/wireprotocol.py", line 210, in _parse_op_response
    raise OperationalError(message, gds_codes, sql_code)
firebirdsql.OperationalError: arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation
Cannot transliterate character between character sets
```

Adding charset both "WIN1251" and "UTF8" doesn't solve the issue. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing as a _"Firebird Interbase database"_. Are you using Firebird, or are you using Interbase?

Comment: In any case, you need to identify which character set was used to store the data, and what the explicit character set is of the column (if it is NONE, you may have a problem).

Comment: If it's NONE, what is my solution?

Comment: Then you need to find out what character set was used by the applications writing into the column (or worse: character sets), and either specify that as the connection character set, apply the right casts or fix the explicit character set of the column.

Comment: "If it's NONE, what is my solution?" - download raw byte streams of the columns and determine used charset on case by case basis. It can be even UTF-16 if Java/.Net/Unicode-Windows progrma was used. Would you save a bytestring into a file you might try TCode http://alexboiko.narod.ru/prod.html#tcode

Comment: Also check if the requested charset was granted to the connection or ignored. See comments panel at https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1462 for diagnostic query to monitoring tables

Comment: If you're really using Interbase, then keep in mind that drivers/libraries written for Firebird are not necessarily compatible with Interbase.